# How Do I Remove a Linked Resource from a Collection in HATEOAS?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

How do I remove a resource from a object's collection using HATEOAS?

A PUT will set the collection.
A PATCH will allow a partial update/add.

But how do I do partial update/remove?

Do I really need to POST the entire uri-list minus 1 in order to remove a single item?

Take this object as an example:

```
{
  "name": "Bob Test",
  "description": "this is the descript",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost/example/1"
    },
    "example": {
      "href": "http://localhost/example/1"
    },
    "citations": {
      "href": "http://localhost/example/1/citations"
    },
   }
}
```

The object has many citations (collection):

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "citations": [
      {
        "content": "asdfasdf",
        "anchor": null,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/citations/1"
          },
          "citation": {
            "href": "http://localhost/citations/1"
          },
          "bioMarker": {
            "href": "http://localhost/citations/1/example"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "content": "c2",
        "anchor": "prf",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/citations/2"
          },
          "citation": {
            "href": "http://localhost/citations/2"
          },
          "bioMarker": {
            "href": "http://localhost/citations/2/example"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost/example/1/citations"
    }
  }
}
```

Now let's say I want to remove `http://localhost/citations/2`, how do I remove this particular item from the `http://localhost/example/1/citations` collection?

Comment: Could you add some of your code for syntax, as well as expected input and output?  It is not totally clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @woemler sure, but outside of orientation, I'm not sure how the hal-json is going to help.

Comment: _"A PATCH will allow a partial update/add."_ Does it? And if it does, isn't removing an item from a collection a partial update of the collection? _"Do I really need to POST the entire uri-list minus 1"_ Don't you mean PUT? POST would add an item. I assume you use Spring Data REST. If so then it's an important fact to mention. HATEOAS doesn't determine how to remove an item from a collection, but the implementation of your service does.

Comment: @zeroflagL the code used to implement the API is a few repositories and domains.  Very slim. Can you provide guidance on how the implementation should remove an item? Just about every resource I've read talks about reading data and very little on updating collections.

Comment: I need more information about the relationship between the resources. It looks like there is a bi-directional relationship. It's not clear if one resource can exist without the other. If a citation cannot exist without an example I suggest to treat example as an aggregate. I wonder why the resources have a link that has the same value as the `self` link. Do the entities point to themselves? You could provide a `http://localhost/example/1/citations/{id of citation}` link, that can be called with `DELETE`.

Comment: On the other hand: The client already has all links in the collection. Sending them back without the one to be deleted is not a big deal. Except if the collection is really large and the items are lazy loaded in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Get the content type from the response and send it in request header "Accept" . Usually it will be "application/xxxxx+json"